# ¿Cómo poder reproducir videos en pantalla completa WebView Youtube Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

cree un web View en Android Studio para esta página: http://www.campusmathema.com/nuevo/ 
El problema está en que no puedo maximizar los videos youtube através del WebView, simplemente el botón no aparece. ¿existe algúna opción que permita realizar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigue estos pasos:

1- Agregue FrameLayout como así:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#000"
        android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

2- En MainActivity:

```
private View mCustomView;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
```

Y En OnCreate():

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.container);
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){


                    @Override
                    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
                        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
                        if (mCustomView != null) {
                            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                            return;
                        }
                        mCustomView = view;
                        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        frameLayout.addView(view);
                        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHideCustomView() {
                        super.onHideCustomView();
                        if (mCustomView == null)
                            return;

                        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        frameLayout.removeView(mCustomView);
                        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

                        mCustomView = null;

                    }

                });
```

Comment: Pero como puede con esto reproducir los videos en pantalla completa?

Comment: Si con esto El botón de pantalla completa estará disponible y así puedes ver los videos en pantalla completa en WebView

Comment: Veo que solo cambia visibilidad del WebView y Framelayout o agrega y quita el WebView del Framelayout pero no veo como podría mostrarse un botón

Comment: Framelayout es invisible , probar ingrese a un video en youtube en tu webview , si no hay nada porfavor publicar tu codigo

Comment: Estimado, tengo un problema con el código, mCustomViewCallback no lo reconoce como variable, se muestra en rojo en android Studio

Comment: @Mr.greystark ya Edité la respuesta

Comment: tu codigo funciona con la pantalla completa, pero al salir de pantalla completo ya no puedo usar el traclado??